# hadoop hdfs java - what is the best way to copy a list of files from hdfs to hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file that has two columns, the first column is the hdfs path to source files, the second column is the hdfs path to target file:

s1, t1
s2, t2
.., ..
sn, tn

what is the fastest way for me to copy the source path to their respective target path.  is there such a tool for hadoop?

The list is probably 100-200 lines long each file is a few megabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The list is probably 100-200 lines long each file is a few megabytes.

If this a one-off kind of situation, then this isn't large enough to worry about. A dumb ol' shell loop will do fine:

```
cat pairs-file | while read pair; do hdfs dfs -cp $pair; done
```